# How to shift bits in a 2-5 byte long bytes object in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-data, bit-shift

I am trying to extract data out of a byte object. For example:
From `b'\x93\x4c\x00'` my integer hides from bit 8 to 21.
I tried to do `bytes >> 3` but that isn't possible with more than one byte.
I also tried to solve this with struct but the byte object must have a specific length.

How can I shift the bits to the right?

Comment: In Perl, you'd use `my $i = ( unpack('N', substr("\x00\x00".$s, -4)) >> 8) & 0x1FFF;`.

Comment: Note that bits are counted from right to left starting at 0; bit 8 is the last bit of the `\x4c` byte, bit 21 through 16 are the last right-most 5 bits of the first byte. Your shift by 3 implies that you are counting bits from left to right; perhaps you are looking for a different set of bits from the convention?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't use `bytes` to represent integer values; if you need bits, [convert to an `int`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes):

```
value = int.from_bytes(your_bytes_value, byteorder='big')
bits_21_to_8 = (value & 0x1fffff) >> 8
```

where the `0x1fffff` mask could also be calculated with:

```
mask = 2 ** 21 - 1
```

Demo:

```
>>> your_bytes_value = b'\x93\x4c\x00'
>>> value = int.from_bytes(your_bytes_value, byteorder='big')
>>> (value & 0x1fffff) >> 8
4940
```

You can then move back to bytes with the [`int.to_bytes()` method](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes):

```
>>> ((value & 0x1fffff) >> 8).to_bytes(2, byteorder='big')
b'\x13L'
```

Comment: For those who find their way here via Google: note that this solution is only appropriate if you are using Python 3.  The `int` class in Python 2 does not have a `from_bytes` method.

Comment: @larsks: yes, the question is specifically tagged with the [tag:python-3.x] tag. :-)

Comment: to get 8-21 bits, you could drop the first 8 bits and take 13 bits from what left: [`(value >> 8) & 0b1_1111_1111_1111`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0515/). To get `n` bits from `x` starting with `offset`: `get_bits = lambda x, n, offset=0: (x >> offset) & ~-(1 << n)`

Answer (score 4):

As you have a bytes string and you want to strip the right-most *eight* bits (i.e. one byte), you can simply it from the bytes string:

```
>>> b'\x93\x4c\x00'[:-1]
b'\x93L'
```

If you want to convert that then to an integer, you can use Python’s [struct](http://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) to unpack it. As you correctly said, you need a fixed size to use structs, so you can just pad the bytes string to add as many zeros as you need:

```
>>> data = b'\x93\x4c\x00'
>>> data[:-1]
b'\x93L'
>>> data[:-1].rjust(4, b'\x00')
b'\x00\x00\x93L'
>>> struct.unpack('>L', data[:-1].rjust(4, b'\x00'))[0]
37708
```

Of course, you can also convert it first, and then shift off the 8 bits from the resulting integer:

```
>>> struct.unpack('>Q', data.rjust(8, b'\x00'))[0] >> 8
37708
```

If you want to make sure that you don’t actually interpret more than those 13 bits (bits 8 to 21), you have to apply the bit mask `0x1FFF` of course:

```
>>> 37708 & 0x1FFF
4940
```

(If you need big-endianness instead, just use `<L` or `<Q` respectively.)

---

If you are really counting the bits from left to right (which would be unusual but okay), then you can use that padding technique too:

```
>>> struct.unpack('>Q', data.ljust(8, b'\x00'))[0] >> 43
1206656
```

Note that we’re adding the padding to the other side, and are shifting it by 43 bits (your 3 bits plus 5 bytes for the padded data we won’t need to look at)

Comment: Note that `int.from_bytes()` doesn't require padding and can take byte sizes larger than 8 as well.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach that works for arbitrarily long byte sequences is to use the [bitstring](http://pythonhosted.org/bitstring/) library which allows for bitwise operations on bitstrings e.g.

```
>>> import bitstring
>>> bitstring.BitArray(bytes=b'\x93\x4c\x00') >> 3
BitArray('0x126980')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your bytes to an integer then multiply or divide by powers of two to accomplish the shifting